# Diffrent way of implementation security ends with the same error

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, static-content

I have implemented an application with combination `Spring Boot` and `Angular 4`. I put all `Angular` files under `/resources/static` directory:

[static directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf1Y8.png)

Then I added to `Spring Security` classes:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.inventory")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/static/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index.html");
    }
}
```

and:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordencoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
```

and it seem that everythings should work. Unfortunately whenever I run my app it throws exception:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not resolve view with name 'index.html' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'.
```

Of course I tried diffrent solution like adding this:

```
@Controller
public class ViewController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/#/")
    public String index() {
        return "forward:/index.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String home() {
        return "forward:/index.html";
    }
}
```

But nothing works. Does anyone has a clue what else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

When using Spring boot normally you don't have to configure resource handler manually, spring boot will automatically load contents from the following loc:

- /static
- /public
- /resources
- /META-INF/resources

see [spring boot guides on loading static contents](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)

Comment: And if you want to provide custom location as in your case, then include this in your handler:
          .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")

Comment: So I changed to: `@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**", "/", "/#/").addResourceLocations("/resources/static/index.html","/resources/static/index.html","/resources/static/index.html");
    }` and it throws  `There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available`

Comment: I don't think you can use # sign in your url, its not meant to be pass in the server.